# Lebesgue integral of a function with value 0 on a set with infinite measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a non-negative function over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$ and let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mu(\{0\})=\infty.$ Is it true that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d\mu(x)
$$

For some $f$, integrals can be infinite, so I would want to know if $\infty = \infty$ in that case. I know this must be super basic, but I am unsure about the exact definitions and the rigor. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the arithmetic of the extended reals, when defining the Lebesgue integral, one defines $0\cdot \infty=0$. So, when you have to multiply $f(0)\cdot \mu(\{0\})$ you get $0$.

Comment: Since $f \cdot 1_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} = f$ then yes.

Comment: See Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* (3rd edition), section 1.22 (page 18). $a\cdot \infty=\infty\cdot a=\begin{cases}\infty,&0<a\leq\infty\\0,& a=0\end{cases}$ and $a+\infty=\infty+a=\infty$ for all $0\leq a\leq \infty$.

Comment: In my opinion, there's some limited utility in learning rules like $0\cdot\infty=0$; but if you want to really learn the subject, you should definitely prioritize becoming sure about the exact definitions, so that you can prove your assertion directly.

Comment: @GregMartin That definition is at the root of proving the identity directly. It is what ultimately makes it true. The identity in general would be $\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}f+f(0)\mu(\{0\})=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$.

Comment: @user85667 My comment was more for the OP (though that was unclear, I see). But I would say that the foundational definitions of Lebesgue integrals is what implies the arithmetic-with-infinities from your comment, not the other way around.

Comment: @GregMartin No, there is nothing in the definition of the Lebesgue integral that would prevent you from defining $\infty\cdot\infty=\infty$. You would do that if for some reason you would like the measure to have more importance than the function in the result. in this case. You would just get different properties. Like $\int_{\mathbb{R}}0=\infty$. Not a very nice property.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was suspecting that the reason is $0 \times \infty = 0$ but I wasn't sure if this is in fact the argument for the above statement to hold. I thought it follows from some other property of the Lebesgue integral.